# Error: cannot load such file -- 2.7/ffi_c when updating CircleCI Ruby image

Tags: ruby, docker, circleci

I'm trying to upgrade from `circleci/ruby:2.7.0-node-browsers` to `cimg/ruby:2.7-node` and I'm getting this error: `cannot load such file -- 2.7/ffi_c`

Before there weren't any problems with the ruby:2.7.0 image.